# Feature file does not recognize an implemented step

Tags: php, testing, bdd, codeception

I'm trying to make a POC using Codeconcept with BDD.
I've created a stepobject and I wanted to use this file for test steps. I've followed https://codeception.com/docs/BDD CONFIGURATION section to autoload the additional steps file since only context files can contain these. When I run `php vendor/bin/codecept gherkin:steps Acceptance` I get this as result:

```
Steps from default context:
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
| Step                                    | Implementation                                                 
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
| The user logs in with the default user. | Tests\Support\Step\Acceptance\LoginSteps::loginWithDefaultUser |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the test with `php vendor/bin/codecept run --debug` the test runs successfully, and when I run the test from PHPStorm itself, the test also runs successfully. Nonetheless, the step is not recognized in the feature file and it is shown as an undefined step reference.

Below you can find all the specs, files, and steps I did:

Specs:

1. PHP version: 8.2.11
2. Codeception version: 5.0.11
3. System: Windows 10 / IDE: PHPStorm

Here are the steps I did:

1. I've installed codeconcept with `composer require codeception/module-webdriver --dev`
2. I've installed the webdriver module with `composer require codeception/module-webdriver --dev --ignore-platform-req=ext-zip`
3. I've run `php vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap` - this generated all suites
4. I've generated one pageobject file with `php vendor/bin/codecept g:pageobject Acceptance Login`
5. I've generated one stebobject file with `php vendor/bin/codecept g:stepobject Acceptance LoginSteps`
6. I've generated one feature file with `php vendor/bin/codecept g:feature Acceptance coupon`

This is how my directory looks like:

```
/codeception
├── codeception.yml
├── tests
│   ├── Acceptance.suite.yml
|   ├── Acceptance
|   |   └── coupon.feature
│   ├── Support
│   │   ├── AcceptanceTester.php
│   │   ├── Step
│   │   │   └── Acceptance
│   │   │       └── LoginSteps.php
|   |   ├── Page
|   |   |   └── Acceptance
|   |   |       └── Login.php
```

**This is the content of** `codeception.yml`:

```
namespace: Tests
support_namespace: Support
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/Support/Data
    support: tests/Support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed

params:
    - .env
```

**This is the content of** `Acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: 'https://test.com/'
            browser: chrome

# add Codeception\Step\Retry trait to AcceptanceTester to enable retries
step_decorators:
    - Codeception\Step\ConditionalAssertion
    - Codeception\Step\TryTo
    - Codeception\Step\Retry

gherkin:
    contexts:
        path: tests/Support/Step
        namespace_prefix: Tests\Support\Step
        default:
            - Tests\Support\AcceptanceTester
```

**This is the content of** `Login.php`:

```
namespace Tests\Support\Page\Acceptance;

use Tests\Support\AcceptanceTester;

class Login
{
    public string $accountField = "input[name='account']";
    public string $emailField = "input[name='mail']";
    public string $passwordField = "input[name='password']";
    public string $loginButton = "button[type='submit']";

    /**
     * @var AcceptanceTester;
     */
    protected AcceptanceTester $acceptanceTester;

    public function __construct(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $this->acceptanceTester = $I;
    }

    public function fillAccountField(string $account): void
    {
        $this->acceptanceTester->fillField($this->accountField, $account);
    }

    public function fillEmailField(string $email): void
    {
        $this->acceptanceTester->fillField($this->emailField, $email);
    }

    public function fillPasswordField(string $password): void
    {
        $this->acceptanceTester->fillField($this->passwordField, $password);
    }

    public function clickLoginButton(): void
    {
        $this->acceptanceTester->click($this->loginButton);
    }

}
```

**This is the content of** `LoginSteps.php`:

```
namespace Tests\Support\Step\Acceptance;

use Codeception\Attribute\When;
use Tests\Support\AcceptanceTester;
use Tests\Support\Page\Acceptance\Login;

class LoginSteps
{

    protected AcceptanceTester $acceptanceTester;

    public function __construct(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $this->acceptanceTester = $I;
    }

    #[When('The user logs in with the default user.')]
    public function loginWithDefaultUser(): void
    {
        $this->acceptanceTester->amOnPage("/");
        $loginPage = new Login($this->acceptanceTester);
        $loginPage->fillAccountField($_ENV['BRAND_NAME']);
        $loginPage->fillEmailField($_ENV['DEFAULT_USERNAME']);
        $loginPage->fillPasswordField($_ENV['DEFAULT_PASSWORD']);
        $loginPage->clickLoginButton();
    }

}
```

**This is the content of** `coupon.feature`:

```
Feature: coupon

  Scenario: try coupon
    * The user logs in with the default user. - THIS STEP IS NOT RECOGNIZED!
```

Am I missing something here?